# expression syntax single field

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've been working on a project which uses a third-party DAL (SubSonic) to produce classes for all database objects.

For querying those objects, the existing code practice has generally been:

```
int keyValue = 1;
TableObject t = TableObject.SingleOrDefault(x => (x.keyField == keyValue));
if (t != null) {
    int valueWeWant = t.fieldWeWant;
    string otherValueWeWant = t.otherFieldWeWant;
}
```

I've been generally trying to reduce the SQL traffic as much as possible, since we tend to have large rows and are often only concerned with one or two fields. So far the best approach I've been able to find is:

```
int keyValue = 1;
var t = TableObject.All().Where(x => (x.keyField == keyValue)).Select(x => new { x.fieldWeWant, x.otherFieldWeWant}).Take(1);
if ((t != null) && (t.Count() != 0)) {
    int valueWeWant = t.First().fieldWeWant;
    string otherValueWeWant = t.First().otherFieldWeWant;
}
```

I like that the generated SQL is only selecting a single row and 2 fields, and am happy with the readability of the anonymous type, but having to compare .Count() seems wasteful to me.

Am I missing a simpler way to perform this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace `Take(1)` with [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx), you would need to check only for `null`, not for the `Count() == 1`, and skip the call of `First()`:

```
var t = TableObject
    .All()
    .Where(x => (x.keyField == keyValue))
    .Select(x => new { x.fieldWeWant, x.otherFieldWeWant})
    .SingleOrDefault();
if (t != null) {
    int valueWeWant = t.fieldWeWant;
    string otherValueWeWant = t.otherFieldWeWant;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect (waiting until SO lets me Accept)!

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea but if you find yourslef using Count() > 0, you will want to use

```
if ((t != null) && (t.Any()))
```

.Any() returns true once it finds the first entity in the collection.  Whereas, .Count() iterates the entire collection before returning true and is a performance hit

Comment: Very good to know, but since I'm doing .Take(1) in the query this answer isn't strictly a good answer for this question.